# Jquery selector issues with dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown menu. In the top level item has a background image ( Carrot indicator ) applied to the href tag on mouse over. I would like to keep or reset the same background image on the parent li href item when the cursor is on the sub menu items. I am a newbie with jQuery please help!

I tired to following but obviously don't know what I am doing

```
$('ul.sub-menu').parent('li a').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css('background-image','/wp-content/themes/wp-crumblemagazine/images    /bg/carrot.gif');
  }, function() {
$(this).css('background-image','none');
  });
   });
});
```

Here is the url to the page

http://mec.staging.wpengine.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your selector didnt return any objects,so its probably wrong...and secondly, i wouldnt make the arrow disappear when entering the submenu in the first place.
+ you also need to position the background image, not just enable it.

but ... a sample with color is below

```
jQuery('ul.sub-menu').parent().find('li>a').hover( function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find("a.sf-with-ul").css('color','red');
},
function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find("a.sf-with-ul").css('color','white');
}
);
```